# How to get most popular combination (set of values, and their count from CSV file as input)

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a CSV file with passengers' travel data:

[image: details about the passenger traveling between different stations and date]
Now using this CSV file as input, we need to find the most popular trip.

***Start Time   End Time    Trip Duration   Start Station   End Station User Type   Gender  Birth Year***
*1/1/2017 0:00  1/1/2017 0:06   356 Canal St & Taylor St    Canal St & Monroe St (*)    Customer

1/1/2017 0:02   1/1/2017 0:08   327 Larrabee St & Menomonee St  Sheffield Ave & Kingsbury St    Subscriber  Male    1984

1/1/2017 0:06   1/1/2017 0:18   745 Orleans St & Chestnut St (NEXT Apts)    Ashland Ave & Blackhawk St  Subscriber  Male    1985

1/1/2017 0:07   1/1/2017 0:12   323 Franklin St & Monroe St Clinton St & Tilden St  Subscriber  Male    1990*

```
*def popular_trip(csv_file):

'''TODO: fill out docstring with description, arguments, and return values.
Question: What is the most popular trip?
'''
# TODO: complete function*
```

Comment: Screenshots don't help, can you just copy/paste that same section of the csv into your question?

Comment: Your question doesn't fit the guidelines. Too broad and no minimal, complete, reproducible example. Data modeling in python is best handled with the pandas library, however, so may as well go ahead and read the docs and get started there.

Comment: How do you define the popular trip? Intuitively I guess, the max repeating value in start_station and end_station is the most famous trip. Do you have any other criteria to define popular trip?

Comment: @AbhijitBalaji - Yes.... you are right..... maximum repeating of combination of start station and end station will be termed as most popular .....
Example -
trips are -> A-B / A-C / A-D / A-B / B-D.... then A-B is most popular with 2 occurrence

Answer (score 0):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"start":['a','a','c','b'],
                   "end":['e','e','g','f']}) #sample df

trip_series = df["start"].astype(str) + " to " + df["end"].astype(str)

trip_series.describe()
```

**output**:

count        4

unique         3

top       a to e

freq           2

dtype: object

```
most_popular_trip = trip_series.describe()["top"]
print(most_popular_trip)
```

**output**: 'a to e'

Comment: Thank you for the code, bt my doubt is...... **what if we have n number of "start" and end "elements" ?** Here we manually added as "a, b, c...." bt **in input csv file unique source and destination stations and their count are not known to us.** How should we proceed in that case ?

Comment: we didn't manually add them, We just told pandas to create a series called "trip_series" to have all the elements of the above two columns. The df["start"] and df["end"] specify the columns, Thus it will work even if you have n number of entries in the columns